# How compose GraphQL query for github

Tags: authentication, github, graphql, github-api-v4

How to present this string as a GraphQL query

```
curl -H "Authorization: bearer token" https://api.github.com/graphql
```

Help me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow "[Forming Calls with GraphQL](https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/forming-calls/)", which involves "[Creating a personal access token for the command line](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line)" to get a token.

Your header should then be: `Authorization: bearer xxx`, with `xxx` being the token you have generated.

As a concrete example: "[Get started with GitHub GraphQL API](https://dev.to/thomasaudo/get-started-with-github-grapql-api--1g8b)".